# Calling the getSignaturesForAddress returns empty

Tags: web3.js, jsonrpc-api, getsignaturesforaddress

Context: I am trying to get a history of transactions for an address. I plan to use the getSignaturesForAddress() to get all the signatures I could use to find all the confirmed transactions using the getTransaction() function. I am currently using the free public RPC node provider and endpoint https://rpc.ankr.com/solana.

```
const publicKey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey('<SOME VALID ADDRESS>'); 
const transSignatures = await solana.getSignaturesForAddress(publicKey);
```

But I have noticed weird results using the getSignaturesForAddress(). For some addresses that I know have transactions, it returns empty or returns only a few of the transactions.

- Am I misusing the getSignaturesForAddress()?
- Is there another way to get a history of transactions?
- Is the public RPC node faulty in that it somehow does not have all the transaction history?

Comment: There is no standard for how much transaction history an rpc provider has to provide, it could theoretically even be none at all. I suggest you check your rpc provider's docs to see how much history they provide and check if this lines up with the transactions you can't seem to find.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. Will check out different rpc providers and their docs, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Elliot Solskjaer mentioned in the comments, there isn't a standard for how much transaction history an rpc provider has to provide.

Instead of using the free public endpoints, I switched to Quicknode's rpc provider and that solved the issue.